# Old emails from 2011 showing up in email

Tags: stock-email-app

In the stock email app, I've suddenly had old emails showing up for no reason.  I haven't changed any settings or linked my account to anything new.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

As the picture shows, there's emails from today and then there's a header that says "older" and then emails from 2011.

I've cleared the data in app info already and then signed back in and the same problem persists.  I've tried simply deleted the header "older" and it comes back.

Comment: I didnt understand the issue. These email seems old emails and if you dont want to see there, you can simply delete.

Comment: There are emails there from today and then it suddenly jumps to the "older" heading and then there are emails from 2011 there.  I've tried deleting them but when the email refreshes to bring in new emails, the older emails show up again.

Comment: Is it the same if you log into the web version of mail provider? If yes, likely a server issue at their end.

Comment: My impression is that the stock Android Mail app is flaky and unreliable. I just discovered that it wasn't actually sending the emails I sent, for about a month, and before that, it ate up 4GB in data out of nowhere (while my total mailbox is only 1.5GB, so reloading everything doesn't explain it).